# Границы блока для текста

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы текст автоматически начинался с новой строки (не через `<br>`), т.е. например, мы задали ширину блока в `15px`, и когда текст дойдёт до границы этого `15px`, он автоматически перенесётся на новую строку в этом же блоке, а не выйдет за границы блока.

---

Код css:
.post{ text-align:left; width:675px; height:auto; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; max-width:675px}

Comment: а задать размеры этому блоку пробовали?

Comment: Да. Ничего не помогает.

Comment: `15px` слишком мало... Пишите буквы через пробел - тогда будет видно перенос))

Comment: это  к примеру. Сам код уже выложил.

Comment: В консоли, либо в адресной строке ( javascript:....) запустите

    m = "aaaaa ";
    res = [];
    for(i=0;i<1000;i++) res.push(m);
    document.body.innerHTML = '<div style = " text-align:left; width:675px; height:auto; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; max-width:675px">' + res.join('')+'</div>'

Comment: Не помогает.

Comment: т.е. у вас напечаталось 1000 слов в одну строку????

Comment: значит нужен полный css, у вас где-то что-то не так)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, по моему Вам нужно: [white-space](http://htmlbook.ru/css/white-space) или [word-wrap](http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-wrap). Тут еще [примерчик](http://www.codertools.com/css_help_guide/css_wrap_white-space.aspx).